# New to Ubuntu but have two problems

Tags: unity, software-center, gnome-classic

I have just installed Ubuntu and I am very pleased, however I have two problems:
I don't have Unity so ran the test and I have been told:

```
Not software rendered: no
GLX texture from pixmap: no
Unity supported: no
```

I really want Unity but due to this I am unaware on what to do.

Also, when downloading software in Ubuntu Software Center it will not let me download apps. It comes up with

```
waiting for apt-get to exit
```

is there anything I need to do so I can download these?
I have the PNY GTX560 and no, I haven't installed any drivers yet as I didn't know I had to.

Comment: where do i find the additional drivers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at `additional drivers` and see if there is a driver that you can install/activate. Always choose the suggested one to start with.

System -> Admin -> Additional drivers.

[image]

Mine looks like this:

[image]

Yours should have 1 or 2 nVidia drivers in it. After you select it it will prompt for your password, install the driver and tell you to reboot. After you do it should automatically switch from `Classic` to `Ubuntu`. If not log out and after selecting your user name look at the bottom for a drop down box where you can choose `classic` and `ubuntu`.

Comment: i click activate and:

Comment: SystemError: E:I wasn't able to locate file for the ttf-mscorefonts-installer package. This might mean you need to manually fix this package
appears it wont let me download apps or do much it seems atm

Comment: got everything to work now so chuffed thanks guys