# Is there a way to active 3d on a Geforce Go 7400?

Tags: nvidia, 11.10

I’m Running Ubuntu 11.10, is it some way to activate 3d acceleration like in the 11.4 or do I have to run it in slow 2d mode.

2d mode works out of the box when fresh installing, but I think 3d was a bit faster.

Comment: If you know how to active Unity 3D in Ubuntu 11.04, then you also know how to do it in Ubuntu 11.10. The action is the same. I know I have done it.

Comment: This question has been asked before and answered.

[How to activate Unity 3D answered][1]


  [1]: http://askubuntu.com/questions/61859/new-to-ubuntu-but-have-two-problems

Comment: Thanks grahammechanical, The solution for nvidia 7400 is to edit a file like this, open a terminal.

Open the file with gedit:
sudo gedit /etc/environment

Add this line att the bottom of the file: 
add: UNITY_FORCE_START=1

Save the file

And reboot

Comment: possible duplicate of [Geforce Go 7300/7400 blacklisted, can I still run Unity?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/37629/geforce-go-7300-7400-blacklisted-can-i-still-run-unity)

Answer (score 1):

You need to add `UNITY_FORCE_START=1`
It's Explained how to do that here: [Geforce Go 7300/7400 Blacklisted, Can I Still Run Unity?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/37629/geforce-go-7300-7400-blacklisted-can-i-still-run-unity)
Also, make sure you have the drivers installed (go to additional drivers and see if there are any for download)

Answer (score 0):

Unity3d doesn't work with Nvidia 7xxx cards. That's why you get the 2d mode, which isn't particularly slow. Bug reports had been files since Natty, but I don't think the 3d mode is going to work.

Here is one:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nux/+bug/728745